# setup logs for neo4j's unmanaged extension

Tags: neo4j

I develope an unmanaged server extension for neo4j 2.3.1. In a code I use slf4j.
Who knows where I can setup appenders for extension's logger?

I would like to log in a separate file. I tried to put custom-logback.xml file inside neo4j/conf but it does not work, all logs come in console.log mixed with other logs.

Thank you.

Comment: In 2.3.x+ you should rename custom-logback.xml to logback.xml

Comment: Thank you Christophe, this works.

Comment: Perhaps post it as an answer Chris